# Hive join over partition

Tags: join, hive, hiveql, partition

I have these 2 tables :

```
table products
(
product_id bigint, 
product_name string
)
partitioned by (product_category as string)

table place_of_sale
(
product_id bigint, 
city string
)
partitioned by (country as string)
```

how can I left join the 2 tables based on 'product_id' but over the partition ‘country’ of the table place_of_sale ?

This is an example with the desired result :

```
table products
product_id      product_name    product_category
1000            banana          fruit
1001            coconut         fruit
1002            ananas          fruit
2002            cow             animal
2003            beef            animal


table place_of_sale
product_id      city        country
1000            Texas       USA
1002            Miami       USA
2003            Sydney      Australia


desired result for a left join between table products and table place_of_sale over the partition country :

product_id      product_name        product_category    city   country
1000            banana              fruit               Texas  USA
1001            coconut             fruit               null   null
1002            ananas              fruit               Miam   USA

2002            cow                 animal              null   null
2003            beef                animal              Sydney Australia
```

Here the example is given with only 2 different countries but imagine plenty of different countries.
It's like a left join performed for each country and then an union between the results of all countries.

Comment: what results do you want. It is not clear what "over the partition ‘country’" means in this context

Comment: I would like to have for each country, the list of product sold & not sold

Comment: Please provide some example, it is not clear what the "list" means. Delimiter separated string per country/product, or array, or you just want one row per product. Not sold means product absent in the 2nd table?

Answer (score 0):

If the sold product is that present in the table place_of_sale, then use LEFT JOIN:

```
select s.country, p.product_id, p.product_name, p.category, 
       case when s.product_id is NULL then "not sold" else "sold" as sold 
 from products p
      left join place_of_sale s on p.product_id = s.product_id 
 order by country, product_id --order if necessary
```